# Can't delete image file by its name or path

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm making a GridView CRUD that saves: **Relation**, **FileName**, **FilePath** (all of them as varchar)in the database, and the image in a folder inside the webpage.

I can already add, select and delete, but the trouble comes when I try to **update**. When I try to update, I successfully modify the database as it's just text. However when the **new image** is uploaded the **old image** remains, I want to delete the old image at the moment of the update so just the new image remains in the file/folder "images", what should I try?

[image]

**(the image is still there after the update)**
[image]

This is my code with the non working deletion of the old image:

BackEnd (just the updating method)

```
protected void gvImages_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = ((FileUpload)gvImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("FileUpload2")).PostedFile;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
    string strQuery = "update testingdb.country set Relation=@Relation, FileName=@FileName, FilePath=@FilePath where idcountry=@idcountry";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
    //string oldFileName = gvImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("images/") + fileName))
    {
        lblFail.Visible = true;
        lblFail.Text = "Ya existe esta entrada.";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {

       //File.Delete(Server.MapPath("images/") + oldFileName);
        //guarda archivos al disco
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" + fileName));

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Relation", (gvImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRel") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "images/" + fileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcountry", Convert.ToInt32(gvImages.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gvImages.EditIndex = -1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblFail.Visible = true;
            lblFail.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

        }
        this.MostrarImagen();
        lblSuccess.Visible = true;
        lblSuccess.Text = "Exito al editar.";
    }
}
```

FontEnd (just the Gridview)

```
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSuccess" Text="" ForeColor="Green" Visible="false"></asp:Label> 

        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFail" Text="" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label> 

        <asp:GridView EmptyDataText="No hay registros en la base de datos!" ID="gvImages" runat="server" DataKeyNames="idcountry" OnRowCommand="gvImages_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvImages_RowDataBound" Height="300px" OnRowEditing="gvImages_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvImages_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvImages_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="idcountry" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Relacion">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Relation") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRel" Text='<%# Eval("Relation") %>'></asp:TextBox> />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNombre2" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FilePath") %>' Height="300" Width="300" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" CssClass="btnOPTIONS" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgBTN/edit.png" Width="30px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                        <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgBTN/delete.png" Width="30px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" CssClass="btnOPTIONS" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgBTN/save.png" Width="30px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                        <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgBTN/cancel.png" Width="30px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I tried with this piece of code but it didn't work (this is in the shown code):

```
//string oldFileName = gvImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
```

and

```
//File.Delete(Server.MapPath("images/") + oldFileName);
```

Also my deleting method doesn't delete the images from the "images" folder, just from the database.

> EDIT: This is what happens when i uncomment those lines of code:
>   [image]

Comment: When i uncomment those lines of code, i get an error saying that those lines of code prevent the access to the database.

Comment: Are you using these images at that moment? Any possibility they may be loaded as image object somehow that could cause them to be locked?

Comment: I'm just using the new image, the old one must be deleted. when I update the gridview the new image appears and the old one disappears but remains in the folder without any use. i want to delete that useless old image, but i can't.

Comment: Side note: you seem to rely on the user's given filename for your own stored file name. That's probably a bad idea; you should do that name management yourself. The user can't _and shouldn't need to_ know what image filenames are already in use on your server. Much safer to either name the file after the country ID, or to store it as BLOB in the database.

Comment: i'll try to store them as a blob, but ill be a muddle.

Comment: Tried like you said, with blobs, but now i have troubles trying to figure a verification: if a name already exists in the database, show a message saying that it already exists. now i can't do that, any idea about how to do a verification of existence in a database with asp.net, c# and mysql? the one i had was:
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("images/") + fileName))
    {
        lblFail.Visible = true;
        lblFail.Text = "Ya existe esta entrada.";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }

Comment: "I get an error saying that [uncommenting] those lines of code prevent the access to the database" - it would be a good idea to add the exact error you get into the question. I can't see how a `File.Delete` operation could interfere with the database - the filing system and the database are two separate things.

Comment: Done, Check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this issue, all i had to do was to change the oldFileName to:

```
    string oldFileName = (gvImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblNombre2") as Label).Text;
```

selecting the data in the label previous to the editing event.

and also:

adding:

```
string mypath = Server.MapPath("images/") + oldFileName;
        File.SetAttributes(mypath, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(mypath);
```

at the end of the connection.

finally... ಥvಥ